# How to hide pop over when click outside in angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I make a simple demo on which I just add rows dynamically. When I press add button and fill the name in input field then press ok it generate a row. So there is a **Star** icon in that I need to show pop over on click. I am able to show pop over. Now I need to hide that pop over when user click outside. I googled it and find one solution which works fine also but it is not like angular can you please tell how I can hide using angular way ..or another way ..?

Second problem is: when I generate a second row and click on the star icon it is not hiding the previous open popovers - why?

http://plnkr.co/edit/46RWSLtxxJgvw5MF1PmM?p=preview

I am able to hide pop over when click outside like this but this jQuery way do you suggest other way ?

```
$('html').on('click', function(e) {
  if (typeof $(e.target).data('original-title') == 'undefined' &&
     !$(e.target).parents().is('.popover.in')) {
    $('[data-original-title]').popover('hide');
  }
});
```

Comment: wait checking .It is working please check.http://plnkr.co/edit/46RWSLtxxJgvw5MF1PmM?p=preview....if it is not working let me know

Comment: You could do this.. http://plnkr.co/edit/C8RQSDGcFxaDSTVJ1PZu?p=preview

Comment: You should consider using angular ui bootstrap popover....

Comment: The [documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover) should be enough to get you started.

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller thanks but it is good when I see plunker.and understand better I already check this documenetation.I don't know how i will apply this on my concept.That why I said please share your anser with plunker

Comment: I understand, but you haven't told us what you've tried. Why don't you create a plunker with your effort and let us know where the problem is, rather than asking us to do it from scratch. Then I'm happy to help. But right now there's no clear question asked and until there is there are dozens of plunkers with popovers, many of which are right here on stack overflow.

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller I tried it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25213447/why-angular-ui-tooltip-not-display-on-button-click

Comment: please look this Question I understant the pop over but when I used costom html or list in that I am fail to display

Comment: i search around 100 thread on stackoverflow .but no one tell how to load html in pop over and get click event on that

Comment: Please understand this isn't an instant messenger platform and responses within minutes should not be expected. With other commitments (like my job), I am only on Stack Overflow a couple times per day. Anyway, that post has been deleted; can you link to a plunker?

Comment: now i get the solution ..if you know about any thing about ths question..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25217933/how-to-make-view-formfrom-json-using-angular.please post it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're not using one of the AngularJS libs that provide a Bootstrap popover, like [this one](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap) to which I've contributed, but the general "angular" solution is to track the state of the popover in the directive and react on click when necessary. E.g.:

```js
// in the link method
isOpen = false

function openPopover () {
  // ... open the popover ...
  // track the state
  isOpen = true;
}

function closePopover () {
  // ... close the popover ...
  // track the state
  isOpen = false;
}

function handleClick ( event ) {
  if ( isOpen ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    closePopover();
  }
};

$rootElement.on( 'click', handleClick );

scope.on( 'destroy', function () {
  $rootElement.off( 'click', handleClick );
});
```

Comment: can you share you plunker ..!!How i will used  Bootstrap popover.if you change my plunker with  angular ui bootstrap popover I will thankfull to you