# how to make view (form)from json using angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to make view from json .When I have array of objects .I am able to make view and validate that view .
If I have this array of object  ,in that case I make able to view ,
check plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/eD4OZ8nqETBACpSMQ7Tm?p=preview

```
[{
            type: "email",
            name: "email",
            required:true
        }, {
            type: "text",
            name: "name",
            required:true
        }, {
            type: "number",
            name: "phonenumber",
            required:true
        }, {
            type: "checkbox",
            name: "whant to check"
        },
            {
                type: "url",
                name: "server Url"
            }];
```

Now the problem occurred when i have json object .I need to show view from json object .I don't know from where I will start work 
I have this json

- "displayName": display the name of label which is from of input text
  field.
- inputValues :represent the type of tmput filled .if it is number then
  user fill only number , text then user only fill number ,email then
  user fill email , if it switch then it is drop down with given
  option.
- "required" give if field is required or not ?

Comment: Are you able to make changes to that Json? Or is it something you do not control?

Comment: No I don't want to change json ..can we use these plugins.https://github.com/danhunsaker/angular-dynamic-forms

Comment: @Fedaykin json is fix .using that json I need to make own json object which then used to make view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `JSON` is coming from a configuration file or a service, you can start by obtaining the `JSON` as a `JSON` object:

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.outputs = {};
    $scope.rawInput = JSON.parse( '{"studentName": "abc", \
        "input": {\
            "loginUser": {\
                "displayDetail": "UserId for login.",\
                "displayName": "Login User Id*",\
                "inputType": "TEXT",\
```

(I had to escape returns to allow the pretty printed `JSON` string to be parsed)

Once you have that, you are nearly there. Now you can just go the level of `JSON` that you require and construct your `inputs` array:

```
$scope.formInputs = $scope.rawInput['input'];
$scope.inputs = [];

angular.forEach($scope.formInputs, function(value, key) {
/* do something for all key: value pairs */
  $scope.inputs.push({"type":value.inputType.toLowerCase(),"name":value.name,"required": value.required})
});
```

Note you should probably do some error checking here - for the purposes of this example, I don't use any.  [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/LTvgRF?p=preview) is a working plnkr that demonstrates this code.

I haven't got it all to work - you'll have to construct your select or radio button inputs, but I think you should be able to take it from here.

**EDIT** I have undated the plnkr to make it public

Comment: plunker is not working please check ..link is not open

Comment: thanks looking for same ..great answer .I need to ask 2 Question how we can make drop drown in that "addFullDataInReport" we have drop drop  with option "true" and "False"

Comment: second Question ? it is good to used this plugin https://github.com/danhunsaker/angular-dynamic-forms.because further I  need to validate my forms.I have around 40 json file so I need to create 40 form so can I use your solution or this plugin with validation

Comment: please check this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/UF6vPoeUFn3FndFKQ1y0?p=preview .I used the plugin but it will not display..

Comment: Hmm not sure about validation. I can't see it in the github project. Unfortunately I don't have any more time to look at this issue, sorry. I'd say that you can use the javascript creation method in my example. But I'm not sure, sorry.