# how to change attribute text of json in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the property name /attr name of my json object.I try like that but nothing will change.I need to make json object after seen the input json and convert it like  outjson

```
function changeData(data){
    var title;
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        if(data[i].hasOwnProperty("displayName")){
            data[i]["label"] = data[i]["displayName"];
            delete data[i]["displayName"];
        }
        if(data[i].hasOwnProperty("displayDetail")){
            data[i]["title"] = data[i]["displayDetail"];
            delete data[i]["displayDetail"];
        }
        if(data[i].hasOwnProperty("inputType")){
            if(data[i]["inputType"]=="NUMBER"){
                data[i]["type"]="number"
            }else  if(data[i]["inputType"]=="TEXT"){
                data[i]["type"]="text"

            }else if(data[i]["inputType"]=="SWTICH"){
                data[i]["type"]="select"
            }
            delete data[i]["inputType"];
        }


    }
    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: why are you treating data as an array?

Comment: You are trying to iterate over an object as if it was an array. That won't work. `data.length` is undefined.

Comment: oh ..sorry i will try..if you get solution .please post it till i am trying

Comment: still not getting out put..:( I used size instead of length

Comment: You probably want a `for.. in` loop e.g. `for (var i in data)`

Comment: @soktinpk please post your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - it's possibe to remove the `if` selection for `inputType` by creating a tiny lookup table from original value to new value:

```
function changeData(data) {

    var map = { NUMBER: "number", TEXT: "text", SWITCH: "select" };

    // data is an object - use for .. in to enumerate
    for (var key in data.input) {
        var e = data.input[key];   // alias for efficient structure dereferencing
        e.label = e.displayName;
        e.title = e.displayDetail;
        e.type = map[e.inputType];

        delete e.displayName;
        delete e.displayDetail;
        delete e.inputType;
    }
};
```

There's really no need for the `hasOwnProperty` test these days - only use it if you think there's any risk that someone unsafely added to `Object.prototype`.   jQuery manages without it quite happily, other modern code should do to.

If the mapping of field names was any longer I'd consider using another mapping table with another loop to remove the hard coded copy/delete pairs.

Comment: can some one help this uestion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25217933/how-to-make-view-formfrom-json-using-angular..if I changed my json to this json befaore making foerm

Comment: @user3703527 sorry, I don't do angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

i have a nice Recursive function for that:

usage:

```
                                                // replace list
var replacedObj = replaceAttrName(sourceObject, {foo: 'foooo', bar: 'baaar'});
```

so in your case you can easily do:

```
var newObj = replaceAttrName(json, {displayDetail: 'title', displayName: 'label', inputType: 'type'});
```

**demo: http://jsfiddle.net/h1u0kq67/15/**

the function is that:

```
function replaceAttrName(sourceObj, replaceList, destObj) {
    destObj = destObj || {};
    for(var prop in sourceObj) {
        if(sourceObj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            if(typeof sourceObj[prop] === 'object') {
                if(replaceList[prop]) {
                    var strName = replaceList[prop];
                    destObj[strName] = {};
                    replaceAttrName(sourceObj[prop], replaceList, destObj[strName]);
                } else if(!replaceList[prop]) {
                    destObj[prop] = {};
                    replaceAttrName(sourceObj[prop], replaceList, destObj[prop]);
                }
            } else if (typeof sourceObj[prop] != 'object') {
                if(replaceList[prop]) {
                    var strName = replaceList[prop];
                    destObj[strName] = sourceObj[prop];
                } else if(!replaceList[prop]) {
                    destObj[prop] = sourceObj[prop];
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    return destObj;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If I am getting you right, you just want substitutions:

- displayDetail => title
- displayName => label
- inputType => type.

I came up with the follwoing:

```
function changeData(data){
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data).replace(/displayDetail/g, "title").replace(/displayName/g, "label").replace(/inputType/g, "type"));
}
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h1u0kq67/2/) to play with.

Edit: I forgot replacements for "NUMBER", "TEXT" and "SWITCH".

```
function changeData(data){
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data).replace(/displayDetail/g, "title").replace(/displayName/g, "label").replace(/inputType/g, "type").replace(/TEXT/g, "text").replace(/NUMBER/g, "number").replace(/SWITCH/g, "switch"));
}
```

Comment: No, why would you want to use regex for json when json is easily parsable?

Comment: but there is one more issue .inputType  may be number or text , seletect mean "NUMBER" become number and "TEXT" become text

Comment: yes, but that would be a replacement like all the other stuff. I overlooked it ;) (it's late here *ggg*)

Comment: i didnot do downvoting...please don't blame me

Comment: @soktinpk why not? If it were tons of JSON and missioncritical code, I would understand your concern. But my solution is much more elegant and easier to understand.

Comment: @user3703527 but you could upvote, if it does, what you intended ;)

Comment: @soktinpk because, my code is easier to read and to understand? I could understand, if your concerns were about performance and this is mission critical code in a realtime system.

Comment: @ThomasJunk I suppose but it is still not "the right way". How do you know it won't become tons of JSON? It isn't as extendable. If there is a better way (that isn't too complicated, and in this case the other way isn't too complicated) you should probably use that instead, right? I don't have numbers but this is probably slower as well.

Comment: @soktinpk If it were literally **tons** I wouldn't do it clientside. So, that's nonsense. I could accept your downvote, if the fastest code possible was asked, but in this case, it's just silly.

Comment: @ThomasJunk Actually, I didn't downvote. But I still don't like this answer that much. But I do see your point (a little).

Comment: please also chck this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25217933/how-to-make-view-formfrom-json-using-angular.cani change my json before making form

Comment: It was my downvote.  I downvoted it because it's an extremely _brittle_ approach to manipulating the data.  Used unwisely (i.e. if someone copied this method on some other piece of data that's maybe not so well formed) it could easily corrupt the data.  Safely manipulating the JS object without having to serialise it and then deserialise it again is trivial.  If you must use a regexp at least ensure you quote the keys, etc, i.e. `replace(/"displayDetail"\s*:/, '"title":')`